# WebDriver capabilities?

Tags: javascript, webdriver, functional-testing

I'm exploring possibilities for automating browser content tests.  WebDriver is something I'm looking at; also, PhantomJS / CasperJS.  It appears easy enough to test for the presence of text content, or of a particular element.  However, what I need is rather more complex.  For instance:

- Need to be able to determine whether text in one element overlaps a bounded area on the screen.
- Need to be able to test for visibility of an element--not merely that it's not set as "hidden" but also that it's not covered up by another element.
- Need to be able to verify correct layout of elements; e.g., that an image is displayed to the right of a block of text, rather than below it.

What it comes down to is the ability to automate the inspection of a Web application to make sure it looks and behaves as it's supposed to.  Are the tools I've mentioned the right sort for this, and will they do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver handles "covered up", but not the other criteria you're looking for.  You might find [Fighting Layout Bugs](http://code.google.com/p/fighting-layout-bugs/) interesting, though, as it tries to deal with exactly those.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you to use Web Driver with java and Sikuli api with java for visual testing. They can work together. You can make Webdriver to find elements by id and sikuli to find elements and locate their position by image, Also you can  use Sikuli OCR to extract text from images and asserting it later, but OCR is not very reliable